# Where should .emscripten LLVM_ROOT and NODE_JS point to? (Mac OS X)

Tags: interpreter, macports, emscripten

After downloading emscripten via

```
git clone git://github.com/kripken/emscripten.git
```

and running

```
./emcc
```

a .emscripten file is created in my user root.

```
==============================================================================
Welcome to Emscripten!

This is the first time any of the Emscripten tools has been run.

A settings file has been copied to ~/.emscripten, at absolute path: /Users/calvin/.emscripten

Please edit that file and change the paths to fit your system. Specifically,
make sure LLVM_ROOT and NODE_JS are correct.

This command will now exit. When you are done editing those paths, re-run it.
==============================================================================
```

I have llvm installed and nodejs installed via macports. So where should I change LLVM_ROOT and NODE_JS to point to?

Comment: I have node.js pre-installed and .emscripten sets NODE_JS to 'node' and I left it like that as I have it in my path. For LLVM_ROOT I downloaded LLVM-3.0 source from llvm.org. AFter build I pointed it to  the Release/bin dir that was created by the build, inside the unpacked llvm-3.0.src dir.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

running `emsdk activate latest` (after having run `emsdk install latest`, which takes a while) gets all of my aliases and such working, I've added it to my bash profile

Answer (score 0):

Are the LLVM / Node.js commands accessible on your path? E.g. does running `node` or `clang` work?

If so, you can detect the paths you need from there. For `LLVM_ROOT`, you want the directory containing the LLVM binaries:

```
$ dirname `which llvm-config`
/usr/local/bin
```

For `NODE_JS`, you want the path to the node binary itself:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

If this fails (because they are not on your path already), then try looking in `/opt/local/bin`. That's seems like the right place from the MacPorts docs (I don't use MacPorts myself).